# RSpec: Need help seeding/understanding Requests Specs & Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to understand RSpec's **request specs** which, to the best of my understanding, are RSpec's equivalent to Integration Tests. I can't seem to seed it correctly with a Race instance. It would seem as though `start_date` and `end_date` are `nil` instead of being actual dates so they fail when being compared to `Date.today` (`self.start_date <= Date.today && self.end_date >= Date.today`).

Here's a basic one that I can't get to pass:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Races" do
  describe "GET /races" do
    it "should display page" do
      Race.create!(:name => "Race Name", :start_date => Date.yesterday, :end_date => Date.tomorrow, :homepage => "http://website.com")
      get races_path
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.should render_template(:index)
    end
  end
end
```

this fails with this error:

```
Failure/Error: get races_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/race.rb:5:in `current?'
     # ./app/helpers/races_helper.rb:12:in `formatted_race_dates'
```

app/models/race.rb:

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
  def current?
    self.start_date <= Date.today && self.end_date >= Date.today
  end
end
```

app/helpers/races_helper.rb:

```
module RacesHelper
  def formatted_race_dates(race)
    link_to(race.homepage, :id => race.current? ? 'live-race' : nil) do
        raw("<strong>#{race.name}</strong> <em>#{race_dates_string(race)}</em>")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup the #start_date is nil for that instance of Race. Probably something in your controller?

Comment: Can you post the index view code? The error refers to the race instance that's in the races helper.